# Dúvida sobre Querys

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando criar uma view para que retorne a consulta de uma Query. Meu problema é que queria que retornasse valores para cada produto e está retornando o mesmo valor para os produtos.

```
SELECT B.ID_Caso, B.Nome_Caso_Teste AS PRODUTO,
(SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Execucao
WHERE (Status_Execucao = 'PASSED')) AS PASSED,
(SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_3
WHERE (Status_Execucao = 'FAILED')) AS FAILED,
(SELECT CAST(COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS float) AS
Expr1
FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_2
WHERE (Status_Execucao = 'PASSED')) /
(SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_1) * 100 AS
PROGRESSO
FROM dbo.Execucao AS A INNER JOIN
dbo.CasoTeste AS B ON A.ID_Caso = B.ID_Caso
GROUP BY B.Nome_Caso_Teste, B.ID_Caso
```

E ele retorna dessa forma, com valores iguais para os produtos, sendo que eles tem dados diferentes. Está consolidando o total e colocando para os produtos.

> ```
> ID_Caso PRODUTO         PASSED FAILED PROGRESSO %
>     4    Condominio        13      5       72,2222222222222
>     3    Empresarial       13      5       72,2222222222222
>     2    Fiança Locatícia  13      5       72,2222222222222
>     1    Residenciais      13      5       72,2222222222222
> ```

Outro problema é que ele está trazendo o campo Progresso quebrado por varias casas decimais, queria que trouxesse inteiro. Por exemplo 72,222222 = 72.
Olhei o forum e não consegui solucionar minha duvida. Alguém pode me indicar um caminho para seguir?

Comment: Teste isso para solucionar o problema das casas decimais: `CONVERT(INT, (subselect * 100)) AS PROGRESSO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro é que nas consultas internas você não considera o id do item, então ele retorna sempre o total. Acredito que isso deva resolver o problema:

```
SELECT B.ID_Caso, B.Nome_Caso_Teste AS PRODUTO,
 (SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_4 WHERE (Status_Execucao = 'PASSED') and B.ID_Caso = Execucao_4.ID_Caso) AS PASSED,
 (SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_3 WHERE (Status_Execucao = 'FAILED') and B.ID_Caso = Execucao_3.ID_Caso) AS FAILED,
 (cast(SELECT CAST(COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS float) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_2 WHERE Status_Execucao = 'PASSED' and B.ID_Caso = Execucao_2.ID_Caso) / 
   (SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1 FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_1) * 100 as numeric(15,0)) AS PROGRESSO
FROM dbo.Execucao AS A INNER JOIN dbo.CasoTeste AS B ON A.ID_Caso = B.ID_Caso
GROUP BY B.Nome_Caso_Teste, B.ID_Caso
```

Comment: Consegui, obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

rLinhares,
tente da seguinte forma:

Coloque em cada where dos sub-selects a clausula

```
     AND ID_Caso = A.ID_Caso
```

para fazer o filtro corretamente.

Quanto ao arredondadamento, pode usar a função FLOOR (arredonda sempre para baixo) da seguinte forma:

```
FLOOR((SELECT CAST(COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS float) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_2
WHERE (Status_Execucao = 'PASSED')) /
(SELECT COUNT(Status_Execucao) AS Expr1
FROM dbo.Execucao AS Execucao_1) * 100) AS
PROGRESSO
```

Tenho uma observação para te fazer, com relação da performance deste select. Esta grande quantidade de sub-querys traz um certo impacto para a consulta, caso execute a consulta excessivamente, te aconselho a mudar a forma de consulta.

Comment: Entendi, vou pensar em uma solução melhor. Obrigado